# C++ Class， the member object in the Class can be created using ’this‘ pointer outside the construct func？

Tags: c++, c++11

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
class myClass;

struct Member
{
    Member(myClass* m)
    {
        std::cout << "member is created" << std::endl;
        my_class = m;
    }
    myClass* my_class;
};



class myClass
{
public:
    myClass()
    {
        std::cout << "myClass is created" << std::endl;
    }

    Member my_member =  Member(this);
    int x = 1;
};

void test() 
{
    myClass mClass;
    std::cout << mClass.my_member.my_class->my_member.my_class->my_member.my_class->x;
}

int main()
{
    test();
}
```

I define a Member Class, and it can construct with a myClass pointer. Importantly, I define the my_member outside the myClass constructor, will it lead to recursive construction？
The code above runs well, is it explainable? 
When does the `this` pointer get created and can be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> will it lead to recursive construction？

No. There is only one `Member` and one `myClass` instance in your example. The `myClass` instance contains a `Member` instance and that `Member` instance has a pointer to the `myClass` instance.

> the code above runs well, is it explainable?

Yes, in the definition of the `Member` class, it doesn't need to know the definition of `myClass` since you only store a pointer to `myClass`. Pointers and references can be created to types of unknown size by forward declaring those types like you do.

> when does the 'this' pointer is created and can be used?

The `this` pointer exists in all non-`static` member functions of instances of your classes.

This:

```cpp
class myClass {
public:
    myClass() {}

    Member my_member = Member(this);
};
```

is equivalent to this:

```cpp
class myClass {
public:
    myClass() : my_member(this) {} // initialized in the member initializer list

    Member my_member;
};
```

... with the addition that in your version, `my_member` will be initialized with `this` when using any `myClass` constructor that doesn't explicitly initialize `my_member` in the member initializer list. The exceptions are the copy and move constructors that will, if `default`ed, copy/move `my_member` with the pointer the copied/moved from object holds.

---

This is what the final C++23 draft has to say about `this`. The example in `7.5.2.5` is pretty close to the code in your question.

**7.5.2 This `[expr.prim.this]`**

1. The keyword `this` names a pointer to the object for which an implicit object member function (11.4.3) is
   invoked or a non-static data member’s initializer (11.4) is evaluated.
2. The *current class* at a program point is the class associated with the innermost class scope containing that point.
3. If a declaration declares a member function or member function template of a class X, the expression `this` is a prvalue of type “pointer to cv-qualifier-seq X” wherever X is the current class between the optional *cv-qualifier-seq* and the end of the *function-definition*, *member-declarator*, or *declarator*. It shall not appear
   within the declaration of either a static member function or an explicit object member function of the current class (although its type and value category are defined within such member functions as they are within an implicit object member function).
   *[Note 2 : This is because declaration matching does not occur until the complete declarator is known. — end note]

   [Note 3 : In a trailing-return-type, the class being defined is not required to be complete for purposes of class member access (7.6.1.5). Class members declared later are not visible.

   [Example 1 :*

   ```cpp
   struct A {
     char g();
     template<class T> auto f(T t) -> decltype(t + g())
       { return t + g(); }
   };
   template auto A::f(int t) -> decltype(t + g());
   ```

   *— end example]

   — end note]*
4. Otherwise, if a member-declarator declares a non-static data member (11.4) of a class X, the expression `this` is a prvalue of type “pointer to X” wherever X is the current class within the optional default member
   initializer (11.4).
5. The expression `this` shall not appear in any other context.
   *[Example 2 :*

   ```cpp
   class Outer {
     int a[sizeof(*this)]; // error: not inside a member function
     unsigned int sz = sizeof(*this); // OK, in default member initializer

     void f() {
       int b[sizeof(*this)]; // OK

       struct Inner {
         int c[sizeof(*this)]; // error: not inside a member function of Inner
       };
     }
   };
   ```

   *— end example]*

---

Sidenote: Since `Member` must be constructed with a pointer to a `myClass` and that it is assumed that `this` pointer is not a `nullptr`, you could make it slightly safer by requiring a `myClass` reference to be used in the constructor instead:

```cpp
struct Member {
    Member(myClass& m) : my_class(&m) {
        std::cout << "member is created" << std::endl;
    }
    myClass* my_class;
};

class myClass {
public:
    myClass() {
        std::cout << "myClass is created" << std::endl;
    }

    Member my_member{*this};

    int x = 1;
};
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Just one more thing though. Please link to a reputable reference —preferably the ISO C++ standard.

Comment: @ChukwujiobiCanon I added the chapter on `this` from the C++23 standard to the answer. I think the example in the last paragraph is especially good. Darn, I now realize that you've tagged it with C++11. You'll find the same example [in there](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/expr.prim#general-5) though.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  for the last paragragh i wonder why it is safer.
if i use like this:
    myClass* ptr = nullptr;
    Member m_member(*ptr);

Comment: @Luci You're welcome! It's safer because `Member` can now be sure that it doesn't get a `nullptr` as an argument to the constructor which means it doesn't have to check that explicitly.

Comment: i see,  it is safer because i can not check the pointer in the initial list. i can check it before passing it into constructor. Thank you very much.